# When does a complex unital *-algebra have a faithful representation on a pre-Hilbert space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex associative unital involutive algebra (*-algebra). Consider all *-representations of $A$ on pre-Hilbert spaces by possibly unbounded operators. Is there a neat criterion on whether there is a faithful such representation? I guess that this is the same as asking whether the universal representation (direct sum of all cylic representations) is faithful. Is there a literature on unbounded * -representations? I have the feeling that my C*-intuition may be misleading.

Thank you.

Comment: I have little to no experience with unbounded operators, so I may be out of touch here. But, is your question well posed? If you have a $*$-representation, you end up with an **algebra** of unbounded operators; that feels like a nightmare to have coherent domains and ranges (since you need sum and composition to be well-defined).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That is exactly why I ask for representations on pre-Hilbert rather than Hilbert spaces. A dense common invariant domain of an algebra of unbounded operators will be a pre-Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes, I missed the "pre Hilbert" part.